# My viewdata spits out HTML,

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-5.1

For some reason my ViewData outputs HTML code even though I don't want it do. 
This is what it

```
<br /><a href="javascript:SetDate('2015-04-01');">2015-04-01</a>
<br /><a href="javascript:SetDate('2015-04-02');">2015-04-02</a>
<br /><a href="javascript:SetDate('2015-04-07');">2015-04-07</a>
<br /><a href="javascript:SetDate('2015-04-08');">2015-04-08</a>
<br /><a href="javascript:SetDate('2015-04-09');">2015-04-09</a>
<br /><a href="javascript:SetDate('2015-04-10');">2015-04-10</a>
```

but I just want it to look like this

```
Du har ej rapporterat tid följande dagar:
2015-04-01
2015-04-02
2015-04-07
2015-04-08
2015-04-09
2015-04-10
```

This is part of my controller:

```
            var missingdays = new DatabaseLayer().GetConsultantMissingDays(Constants.CurrentUser(User.Identity.Name));
        if (missingdays.Count == 0)
        {
            ViewData["missingDays"] = "";
        }
        else
            ViewData["missingDays"] = "Du har ej rapporterat tid följande dagar:<br />" +
                                      string.Join("<br />", missingdays.Select(x => x.ToMissingDateJavascript()));

        ViewData.Model = projectData;

        return View();
    }
```

And this is from my view:

```
<div>
    @ViewData["missingDays"]
    @Html.ValidationSummary()
</div>
```

and my Extensions

```
        public static string ToMissingDateJavascript(this DateTime value) {
        string dateString = value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        return "<a href=\"javascript:SetDate('" + dateString + "');\">" + dateString + "</a>";
    }        

    public static bool IsWeekend(this DateTime value) {
        return value.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday || value.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday;
    }
```

But I see the HTML code in the browser
[image]

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Are you seeing HTML codes in the browser window?

Comment: Yes. I am seeing the HTML code in the browser window.

Comment: You should use `@Html.Raw(ViewData["missingDays"])`

Comment: After formatting your code - I see no difference between what you got and what you want. Why are you joining the strings instead of just looping over the data, as shown in all Razor examples?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The problem is that the HTML is being shown to the user in the browser.

Comment: You should **NOT** try to generate HTML in your controller, that's the View's job. Pass the list to the view and iterate over the list of items there, generating the HTML you want for each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MVC the View is supposed to execute all work related to generating HTML, not the Controller. You can rewrite and simplify both the view and the controller as follows:

View:

```
@foreach(var date in ViewBag.MissingDays){
    var isoDate=date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
    <br/><a href="javascript:SetDate('@isodDate');">@isoDate</a>
}
```

Controller:

```
//Assuming that missingdays is a List<DateTime> or other IEnumerable<DateTime>
ViewBag.MissingDays=missingdays;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can wrap the call in [`Html.Raw()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg480740(v=vs.118).aspx), like this:

```
@Html.Raw(ViewData["missingDays"])
```

However, it is better to pass in an array rather than HTML (or even passing it in the view model). You should avoid using any HTML in your controller as much as possible. For example:

```
@foreach(var date in (List<DateTime>)ViewData["stuff"])
{
    <a href="javascript:SetDate('@date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")');">
        @date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
    </a>
    <br/>
}
```

Noet: I would also suggest not using `br` tags here and format with CSS.

Comment: `mm` is minutes, `MM` should be used for months

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Till the day I die, I will never remember which way round it is supposed to be!

Comment: That's why DateTime formatting/parsing questions in SO are so common

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to convert the string to HTML:

```
@{
     string missingDays = ViewData["missingDays"]
}
@MvcHtmlString.Create(missingDays)
```